# Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at :MainTimeline/loop()_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:190]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im making a platform game and i can't figure out what's the problem specifically it says the problem is in this line:

```
if(background_mc.platform_mc.hitTestPoint(player_mc.x-xDistance,player_mc.y, true))
```

Comment: Do all of the objects, backgound_mc, platform_mc, and player_mc exist? What is the value of xDistance?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem you need to trace() all the objects you are referencing in this line prior to it:

```
trace("background_mc", background_mc);
trace("player_mc", player_mc);
trace("platform_mc", background_mc.platform_mc);

if(background_mc.platform_mc.hitTestPoint(player_mc.x-xDistance,player_mc.y, true))
```

One of the traces will give you either "undefined" or "null" and then you can move on to the next step: why do you think the object must be accessible while it is not.